# Why I got "Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))" when creating user in Active Directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory

I use the following code to create user in Active Directory

```
DirectoryEntry newUser = null;
            try
            {
                if (!Authenticate()) return null;

                newUser = location.Children.Add("CN=" + userName, "user");
                newUser.Properties["samAccountName"].Value = userName;
                newUser.Properties["cn"].Value = userName;

                newUser.CommitChanges();
                string guid = newUser.Guid.ToString();
                newUser.Invoke("SetPassword", new object[] { password });
                newUser.CommitChanges();
                DomainDirectoryEntry.Close();
                newUser.Close();
                return guid;
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                newUser = null;
            }
```

If I run this code from asp.net web page it create the user in Active Directory and it created disabled but it throw exception `Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.` and when i get the inner exception of this exception it get me `Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDEN` I'm sure that the account that i use to access Active Directory is a full admin ..

I don't determined the reason and why it's create the user but it generate error on setting password ... Could any guide me to get the error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried many approaches and by end we found that the problem appear when code run from SharePoint so we put the code in the below code and it run successfully

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
  {
     ......
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you (App Pool User or Impersonated User) don't have permissions to do that.

By default the user will be NETWORK SERVICE which i am certain doesn't have the permission for that.

How do you know which account you are using to access Active Directory?

Comment: but is App pool user affect even i use domain admin user to access active directory from code ...